# how do I maintain message location for each input text?

Tags: javascript

I am designing a form which includes multiple input textbox. I want to show user an error message when they focus their mouse in the text field but not input anything. I did the first one textbox ok with addEventListener focus and blur. I did the second use the same code. The problem is that if I input text in first text box and leave the second one empty but focused, the error message is located in first text error message. I think I should do something with the error message location.

HTML code:

```
<form name="myform">
            <div>
                <label for="name">NAME* :</label>
                <input type="text" id="nameInput" name="nameInput">
                <div id="nameError" class="error"></div> 
            </div>
            <div>
                    <label for="email">EMAIL* :</label>
                    <input type="text" id="emailInput" name="emailInput">
                    <div id="emailError" class="error"></div>               
            </div>
</form>
```

Javascript code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    let hasAttempted1 = false;
    let hasAttempted2 = false;
    placeOrder.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const name = document.forms["myform"]["nameInput"].value;
        const email = document.forms["myform"]["emailInput"].value;
    });
    //check if user put curser in the text box
    nameInput.addEventListener("focus", () => {
        hasAttempted1 = true;
    });

    emailInput.addEventListener("focus", () => {
        hasAttempted2 = true;
    });
    // if user do not put anything 
    nameInput.addEventListener("blur", () => {
        if (document.forms["myform"]["nameInput"].value.length == 0)
        {   
            nameError.innerHTML = `Required an input`;
        }
    });

    // if user do not put anything 
    emailInput.addEventListener("blur", () => {
        if (document.forms["myform"]["emailInput"].value.length == 0)
        {
            emailError.innerHTML = `Required an input`;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution validates the `name` and `email` inputs at the appropriate times by **using the `validateInput` function** at the bottom of the snippet.
(Both the `validateOnBlur` listener and the `tryToPlaceOrder` listener rely on it.)

Note that the **error divs are hidden** by default, and become visible when the `validateInput` function removes the `hidden` class.

And the `inputFocused` function sets a data attribute (called `data-attempted`) on the input element itself, rather than storing the state information for each input in a global variable. (These attributes go unused, however, since the validation didn't need this information.)

```js
const
  // Defines helper functions
  gebId = (id) => document.getElementById(id),
  ael = (el, e, f) => el.addEventListener(e, f),

  // Selects DOM elements we will need
  nameInput =     gebId("nameInput"),
  emailInput =    gebId("emailInput"),
  placeOrderBtn = gebId("placeOrderBtn"),
  outputDiv =     gebId("output");

// Sets listeners for user interface
ael( nameInput,     "focus", inputFocused );
ael( nameInput,     "blur",  validateOnBlur );
ael( emailInput,    "focus", inputFocused );
ael( emailInput,    "blur",  validateOnBlur );
ael( placeOrderBtn, "click", tryToPlaceOrder );


// Defines focus listener
function inputFocused(e){

  // When an element is target of focus event, gives 
  // the element a `data-attempted` attribute w/ value of "true"
  e.target.dataset.attempted = "true";
}

// Defines blur listener
function validateOnBlur(e){

  // When an (input) element is target of blur event,
  // applies the `validateInput` function to the element
  validateInput(e.target);
};

// Defines click listener
function tryToPlaceOrder(e){

  // When a (button) element is target of click event,
  // validates inputs. (If valid, clears inputs and prints values)
  let
    name,
    email;
  if(

    // This condition evaluates to false if any input is invalid
      (name = validateInput(nameInput)) &&
      (email = validateInput(emailInput))
  ){

    // All inputs are valid. Clears inputs and prints values.
    nameInput.value = "";
    emailInput.value = "";
    nameInput.focus();

    const output = `Order placed for: ${name} (${email})<br/>`;
    outputDiv.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", output);
  }
};


// Defines validation function
function validateInput(input){
  // (Returns the value of the input if it is valid)

  // If an input element has no characters...
  if(input.value.length === 0){

    // ...removes the `hidden` class from the following element,
    // gives focus back to input, and returns undefined...
    input.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("hidden");
    input.focus();
 }
  else{

    // ...Otherwise adds the `hidden` class to following element 
    //    and returns the value of the input
    input.nextElementSibling.classList.add("hidden");
    return input.value;
  }
}
```

```css
.group, button{ margin-bottom: 0.5em; }
.error{ color: red; }
.hidden{ display: none; }
#outputdiv{ color: blue; }
```

```html
<form name="myform">
  <div class="group">
    <label for="name">NAME* :</label>
    <input id="nameInput" name="nameInput" />
    <!-- Some elements have `hidden` class by default -->
    <div id="nameError" class="error hidden">
      Please enter a name
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label for="email">EMAIL* :</label>
    <input id="emailInput" type="email" />
    <div id="emailError" class="error hidden">
      Please enter an email address
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<button id="placeOrderBtn">Place Order</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

A suggested improvement would be to get the inputs using a different DOM method (such as `getElementsByTagName`) and convert the resulting list of **inputs to an array** (with `Array.from()`.)

Because most of the code that deals with inputs does the exact same thing with each input (eg adding event listeners, submitting an order), it would be cleaner to iterate through them -- although as long as there are only two inputs, the repetition of code is not too heinous.

Another alternative would be to use **a single `focus` listener and a single `blur` listener** added to an ancestor element (possibly the form itself) rather than giving each input its own listeners, which is somewhat wasteful.